# How do I parse this XML string with multiple nodes in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, parsing

I am submitting data with WebRequest, and I receive the following with the WebResponse:

```
<tss_loan_response>
    <signature>
        <data name="page">app_completed</data> 
        <data name="site_type">soap_pw</data> 
        <data name="license_key">lic.olp.bb.sample</data> 
        <data name="promo_id">99999</data> 
        <data name="promo_sub_code">test</data> 
        <data name="unique_id">b315782da42f23edec5c32adfe39a457</data> 
        <data name="environment">testing</data> 
    </signature>
    <errors /> 
        <content>
            <section>
                <url>https://rcredirect.tridentsecuredata.com/b315782da42f23edec5c32adfe39a457</url> 
            </section>
        </content>
    <collection>
        <data name="client_url_root">SAMPLE.COM</data> 
        <data name="client_ip_address">127.0.0.1</data> 
        <data name="customer_id">D6FC0D89-8741-484D-9E76-3E8264702059</data> 
    </collection>
</tss_loan_response>
```

After I get the response, I want to set the values of each XML tag/line to a variable (so I can use them after it's done reading the file).

I've been trying everything and can't seem to get it working.  Any thoughts?

I'm using ASP.NET and C#.

Comment: Read it into an object, a dictionary, whatever.  Show us what you've been trying...

Comment: I've probably gotten closest with this: `var query = xdoc.Descendants("signature")
       .Elements()
       .ToDictionary(r => r.Attribute("name").Value,
           r => r.Value);`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get it to work:

```
var signatureElement = XElement.Parse(responseFromServer).Descendants("signature")
                            .Elements()
                            .ToDictionary(r => r.Attribute("name").Value,
                                         r => r.Value);

string pageXML = signatureElement.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "page").Value;
```

Comment: Because `signatureElement` is `Dictionary<string, string>` you don't have to use `FirstOrDefault` to get `"Page"` element. Use standard index notation: `string pageXML = signatureElement["page"];`